# cleartool update error in Solaris Unix

Tags: unix, solaris, cleartool

I am working on a view created from the main code repository on a Solaris server. I have modified a part of the code on my view and now I wish to update the code in my view to have the latest code from the repository. However when I do

```
cleartool update .
```

from the current directory to update all the files in the current directory, some(not all) of the files do not get updated and the message I get is

```
Keeping hijacked object <filePath> - base no longer known.
```

I am very sure that I have not modified the directory structure in my view nor has it been modified on the server repository. One hack that I discovered is to move the files that could not be updated to a different filename(essentially meaning that files with original filename no longer exist on my view) and then run the update command. But I do not want to work this out one by one for all the files. This also means I will have to perform the merge myself.

Has someone encountered this problem before? Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comment VonC. I did check out the link you mentioned, but I did not find it much useful as I had not renamed any directory. After spending the whole day yesterday, I figured out that I had modified some of the files previously without checking them out first. This made me to modify them forecfully as they were in read-only mode as they were not checked-out. This resulted in those files to become hijacked, and hence when I tried to update my view to look at all the modifications in the repository, it was unable to merge my modified file with that on the server as those files were modified without being checked out so the cleartool update was made to believe that the file is not modified(since it was not checked out) but actually it was. That was the fuss!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try a "`cleartool update -overwrite`" (see [`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)), as it should force the update of all files, hijacked or not.

But this message, according to the [IBM technote swg1PK94061](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK94061), is the result of:

> When you rename a directory in a snapshot view, updating the view will cause files in the  to become hijacked.
>
> Problem conclusion
>
> Closing this APAR as No Plans To Fix (NPTF) because:
>
> - (a) to the **simple workaround of deleting the local copy of renamed directories** which will mitigate the snapshot view update problem and
> - (b) because of this issue's low relative priority with higher impact defects

So simply delete (or move) the directory you have rename, relaunch you update, and said directory (and its updated content) will be restored.